# tidyr::pivot_longer() with duplicate problems with no apparent duplicate column names or dataset in R

Tags: r

[image]My goal is to change value 99999 with the value adjacent to it unless it's 99999 again.
I took the advice from here before, now I am having a new problem.

***MRE:***
'as' is a dataframe with 9 different cohort datasets; 10030 obs of 7060 variables. I am mainly (as of now) dealing with `as$AS1_WEIGHT` ... `as$AS9_WEIGHT`

```
> as %>%
+     select(starts_with("AS") & ends_with("_WEIGHT")) %>% head() %>% dput()

structure(list(AS1_WEIGHT = c(72, 59, 50, 55.2, 82.1, 50.4), 
    AS2_WEIGHT = c(74.8, NA, NA, 54.8, 84.5, 52.5), AS3_WEIGHT = c(75.2, 
    NA, NA, 55.9, 81.7, 54.6), AS4_WEIGHT = c(75, NA, NA, 55.1, 
    80.6, NA), AS5_WEIGHT = c(75.4, NA, NA, 58.8, 89.5, NA), 
    AS6_WEIGHT = c(77.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AS7_WEIGHT = c(70.7, 
    NA, NA, 56, NA, NA), AS8_WEIGHT = c(73.8, NA, NA, 55.5, NA, 
    NA), AS9_WEIGHT = c(74.5, NA, NA, 54.8, NA, 52)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
as %<>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(starts_with("AS") & ends_with("_WEIGHT")) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(value == '99999', lead(value), value), .by = row) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

returns:

Error in `tidyr::pivot_longer()`:
! Names must be unique.
✖ These names are duplicated:

- "name" at locations 7049 and 7053.
- "value" at locations 7050 and 7054.
  ℹ Use argument `names_repair` to specify repair strategy.
  Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

So I ran this code to see which columns are duplicated:

```
> dup_col <- duplicated(base::as.list(as))
colnames(as[dup_col])

character(0)
```

I ran another code to see if I am referring to the right columns

```
> as %>%
  select(starts_with("AS") & ends_with("_WEIGHT")) %>%
  colnames()

[1] "AS1_WEIGHT" "AS2_WEIGHT" "AS3_WEIGHT" "AS4_WEIGHT" "AS5_WEIGHT" "AS6_WEIGHT" "AS7_WEIGHT" "AS8_WEIGHT"
[9] "AS9_WEIGHT"
```

> Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to use an example that contains 99999. The example you gave does not contain the number in question

Comment: Your MRE runs fine for me. Is it possible that the MRE doesn't include the problem column?

Comment: @Onyambu I will try to be more meticulous in uploading MRE.

Comment: @Taren Sanders yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you already have a column named `name` or `value` before you run pivot_longer, which by default tries to create columns with those names. As noted [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1494), the error message isn't necessarily clear that's the problem.

Try `grep("name", colnames(as))` and `grep("value", colnames(as))` to find those columns.

Either rename in your data frame or use `pivot_longer( ... names_to = "a_new_name_col", values_to = "a_new_value_col")`

```
data.frame(a = 1:2, name = 3:4, value = 7:8) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(a)
#Error in `vec_cbind()`:
#! Names must be unique.
#✖ These names are duplicated:
#  * "name" at locations 1 and 3.
#  * "value" at locations 2 and 4.
#ℹ Use argument `names_repair` to specify repair strategy.
#Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

data.frame(a = 1:2, name2 = 3:4, value2 = 7:8) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(a)
## A tibble: 2 × 4
#  name2 value2 name  value
#  <int>  <int> <chr> <int>
#1     3      7 a         1
#2     4      8 a         2
```

Comment: ```> grep("name", colnames(as)) [1] 7058``` and ```> grep("value", colnames(as)) [1] 7059```    . ```> sum(grepl("value", colnames(as))) [1] 1``` and ```> sum(grepl("name", colnames(as))) [1] 1```

Comment: There were 2 problematic columns. Thank you.